# Correctly Formatting URL with variable(s)

Tags: php

I have the following line below as a URL

*//someplace/forum/view_topic.php?cid=1&tid=2*

I would like replace cid &  tid for the below values

```
$topic_tid= $row->cat_id;

$topic_id= $row->id;
```

I have tried the following (Not Working)

```
echo "<a href=view_topic.php?cid=".$topic_id."&tid"=.$topic_tid.">Result</a>";
```

How can I correctly format the above line please

Comment: Because second `=` should be in quotes.

Comment: You're missing an opening quote after `<a href=`.

Comment: @u_mulder Thank You , Working .

Comment: @JethroVanThuyne Thanks I see that now you pointed it out also . Working now .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use  proper quotes (single) for href assign and proper content in "&tid=" (missing = .. your is outside the string)

```
echo "<a href='view_topic.php?cid=".$topic_id."&tid=".$topic_tid."'>Result</a>";
```

Comment: Inside double quotes, the variables are expanded automatically, so the concatenating dots aren't really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your code more readable, like the sample below. By building your link outside ouf the echo statement, you can see more clearly what was going wrong (a missing quote after href):

```
$link = "view_topic.php?cid=$topic_id&tid=$topic_tid";
echo '<a href="' . $link . '">Result</a>';
```

Comment: Thats a way better way of making the links readable. I have applied this method now and in future for all others .